# Merge two timeseries data and sync the datetime?

Tags: java, python, pandas

I got multiple data sets with multiple columns
say data1:-

```
datetime              ch1[d1]   ch2[d1] ......
2019-07-27 16:40:28    20        21
2019-07-27 16:41:28    22        13
2019-07-27 16:42:28    12        21
.
.
.
.
```

data2:-

```
datetime              ch1[d2] .....
2019-07-27 16:43:28    20    
2019-07-27 16:44:28    22    
2019-07-27 16:45:28    12  
.
.
.
.
```

final data:-

```
datetime              ch1[d1]   ch2[d1]  ch1[d1] ......
2019-07-27 16:40:28    20         21      nan
2019-07-27 16:41:28    22         13      nan
2019-07-27 16:42:28    12         21      nan
2019-07-27 16:43:28    nan        nan     20
2019-07-27 16:44:28    nan        nan     22
2019-07-27 16:45:28    nan        nan     12
.
.
.
.
```

Any suggestions how can i achieve this,i am using java as programming language,or any third party utility that can be useful.

Comment: Try an outer join: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment above said, you can use an outer join to accomplish what you're after:

```
data1 = pd.DataFrame({"datetime": ["2019-07-27 16:40:28", "2019-07-27 16:41:28", "2019-07-27 16:42:28"], 
                  "ch1d1": [20, 22, 12], 
                  "ch2d1": [21, 13, 21]})
data1 = data1.set_index("datetime")
data1

                     ch1d1   ch2d1
datetime        
2019-07-27 16:40:28     20      21
2019-07-27 16:41:28     22      13
2019-07-27 16:42:28     12      21

data2 = pd.DataFrame({"datetime": ["2019-07-27 16:43:28", "2019-07-27 16:44:28", "2019-07-27 16:45:28"], 
                  "ch1d2": [20, 22, 12]})
data2 = data2.set_index("datetime")
data2

                     ch1d2
datetime    
2019-07-27 16:43:28     20
2019-07-27 16:44:28     22
2019-07-27 16:45:28     12

data1.join(data2, how = "outer")

                       ch1d1    ch2d1   ch1d2
 datetime           
2019-07-27 16:40:28     20.0    21.0    NaN
2019-07-27 16:41:28     22.0    13.0    NaN
2019-07-27 16:42:28     12.0    21.0    NaN
2019-07-27 16:43:28     NaN     NaN     20.0
2019-07-27 16:44:28     NaN     NaN     22.0
2019-07-27 16:45:28     NaN     NaN     12.0
```